# How do I extract certain items from unstructured text?

Tags: r

I have an extremely unstructured data frame (df) in R, which includes a text column.

An example of the df$text looks like this

```
John Smith 3.8 GPA johnsmith@gmail.com, https://link.com
```

I am trying to extract the GPA out of the field and save to a new column called df$GPA but am unable to get it to work.

I have tried:

```
df$gpa <- sub('[0-9].[0-9] GPA',"\\1", df$text)
```

But that returns the whole block of text.

I am also trying to extract the url but am unsure how to do that as well.Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the url always the last bit of the string preceded by a comma and space? What range of url complexity is included in your data?

Comment: @Peter not always. Just included one example

Comment: Your current regex is insufficient because all you do is replace `"3.8 GPS"` with `"3.8"`. Change your pattern to `sub(".*\\b([0-9]\\.[0-9]) GPA.*", "\\1", ...)` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using positive lookahead in `(?=GPA)`and `str_extract`from the package `stringr`:

```
df$GPA <- str_extract(df$text, "\\d+\\.\\d+\\s(?=GPA)")
```

A `sub`solution with backreference would be this:

```
df$GPA <- sub(".*(\\d+\\.\\d+).*", "\\1", df$text)
```

Result:

```
df
                                                      text GPA
1 John Smith 3.8 GPA johnsmith@gmail.com, https://link.com 3.8
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(text = "John Smith 3.8 GPA johnsmith@gmail.com, https://link.com")
```

Comment: You're a computational linguist.  What are your 'go-to' R packages for computational linguistics?  I know about `tm` and `SnowballC`.  What other packages should I become learned in?  I'm most interested in similarity measurements between short strings of text, for classification to taxonomies.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that. I'm a linguist doing linguistics with the computer. That doesn't make me a computational linguist.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regex lookaround to extract the numeric part

```
library(stringr)
df$GPA <- str_extract(df$text, "[0-9.]+(?=\\s*GPA)")
df$GPA
#[1] "3.8"
```

---

Or in `base R` with `regmatches/regexpr`

```
regmatches(df$text, regexpr("[0-9.]+(?=\\s*GPA)", df$text, perl = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(text = 'John Smith 3.8 GPA johnsmith@gmail.com, https://link.com', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```